# Salesforce SOQL to fetch all the accounts assigned to the logged in user

Tags: rest, salesforce, soql

I have the accessToken of the logged in user and currently my query looks like below

```
https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/query?q=SELECT Id,Name,Industry,Ownership,AnnualRevenue,NumberOfEmployees,Phone,Website FROM account ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 10
```

The above query will return last 10 modified accounts that the loggedin user has access to. What I want is to get only those accounts that are assigned to the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

You need a query similar to

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE OwnerId = '005...'
ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

All users' ids in all SF instances in the world start with 005.

You can get the user id from the login success response. Which OAuth2 flow you've used? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5 ?

In that example the user's id is hidden in the OAuth "id" field (identity, service that returns some info about the user. name, email, preferred language, locale, timezone...)

```
https://www.customercontactinfo.com/user_callback.jsp#
access_token=00Dx0000000BV7z%21AR8AQBM8J_xr9kLqmZIRyQxZgLcM4HVi41aGtW0qW3JCzf5xd
TGGGSoVim8FfJkZEqxbjaFbberKGk8v8AnYrvChG4qJbQo8&
refresh_token=5Aep8614iLM.Dq661ePDmPEgaAW9Oh_L3JKkDpB4xReb54_pZfVti1dPEk8aimw4Hr9ne7VXXVSIQ%3D%3D&
instance_url=https://yourInstance.salesforce.com&
id=https://login.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00Dx0000000BV7z%2F005x00000012Q9P&
issued_at=1278448101416&
signature=miQQ1J4sdMPiduBsvyRYPCDozqhe43KRc1i9LmZHR70%3D&
scope=id+api+refresh_token&
token_type=Bearer&
state=mystate
```

It's bit hard to see but if you would receive this response you need to extract the `005x00000012Q9P` part. If you don't trust parsing that url - well, call that "id" endpoint. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/11728/799 for response format and some more ideas.